# XCode - Close keyboard on buttonclick

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I just started playing around with XCode a few hours ago, doing the HelloWorld tutorial.
I managed to close the keyboard window when the user clicks the Return button.

However, my button should have the exact same behavior as the Return button. It does the same right now, it just doens't close down the keyboard upon submission. How can i do this?

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    [self changeLabelWithText: self.textField.text];

}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];

        [self changeLabelWithText: self.label.text];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)changeLabelWithText: (NSString *) text {
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hej, %@", text];
}
```

Comment: resign your `textfield` in button method. In your button method give `[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

[textFieldName resignFirstResponder];

Comment: Using [textField resignFirstResponder] is not working. I am pretty sure I need to identify it first, so it knows it's a text field object with the name textField. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

Or you can do this (this way you do not care which text field/view it is).

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: This works well when you have multiple textFields in the view.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
        [TextFieldobj resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: How do I get the textField object? The name of the textfield is textField

Comment: I ask again, how do I get the textField object? I cannot give the object without getting it first

Comment: UITextField *textFieldobj = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 280, 31)];  Just give [textFieldobj resignFirstResponder];

Comment: As far as I can guess, that is going to create a new Text Field. This is not what I need.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21449/discussion-between-bing-and-patrick-reck)

Comment: If you'll save your textField as member, so you can access it anytime.